# ABORT function not working in expression transformation informatica

Tags: informatica

I have a scenario where in need to compare the amount and if they don't match ABORT  the session.
 I have done the below logic,  but some how the ABORT function is not working.(Error says has an error evaluating variable column)

this is what i did:
i have 3 source columns `DLY_NET_AMT_DUE, WKLY_INVCD_AMT, INV_CHARGE_AMOUNT`. All  are inputs. I used a variable port and said

`v_INV_CHARGE_AMOUNT=iif((DLY_NET_AMT_DUE=WKLY_INVCD_AMT) and 
(WKLY_INVCD_AMT=INV_CHARGE_AMOUNT),'Amount Balanced',ABORT('Amount Not Balanced'))`

`o_INV_CHARGE_AMOUNT=v_INV_CHARGE_AMOUNT`

Could you guys please help me where  am i going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please paste the exact error message.
2. If possible, share the transformation screenshot
3. What is the datatype of v_INV_CHARGE_AMOUNT port? Is it possible that it's decimal and the error is caused by trying to put `Amount Balanced` as value?
4. Did you try to run debugger and do the `Evaluate expression`?